# Java adding an ArrayList to Existing Object

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having some trouble with one of my methods. A brief overview of what my method is supposed to do.  Here's what I have so far.

```
public boolean addGame(String team1, String team2) {
    boolean result;

    if (team1.equals(team2))
        result = false;

    }
    if (a game between two parameter teams has previously been added by
        earlier call to addGame){ 
        result = false;
    }
    else { 
        result = true; 
    }
```

I want my method to return false if a game between two parameter teams has previously been added to the conference object by an earlier call to addGame and 
if the name of team1 and team2 are the same name.

My issue is the syntax for what's inside of my second if statement. Not sure how to go about it.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Step 1: Store the games you've seen so far into your favourite data structure.

Comment: i've stored all games in a separate arraylist...once I do that then? @JoeC

Comment: Check whether the said ArrayList `contains` the game you're after, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how long you plan on saving the information. If it is just in the runtime, you can do something such as saving the two teams to an array.

If you want to save it for a longer time, you need some way of persisting the information, possibly a table in a database?

Then, you can query to data and check if the combination existed already.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a history of the added teams:

```
ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<String>();

//As you add the teams
history.add(teamName);  //add to history as well

//To check if teams already exist or added before
if(history.contains(team1) || history.contains(team2)){
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ArrayList called games, and the games are stored in the format "team1;team2", then you can do `games.indexOf(team1 + ";" + team2) == -1` for the if statement.